# Migration of Merge statement from teradata to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Tables:-
**schema.INFA_TASK_RUN_STG
schema.INFA_TASK_RUN**

**Primary Index of schema.INFA_TASK_RUN_STG**  :- SUBJECT_AREA
**Primary Index of schema.INFA_TASK_RUN** :- SUBJECT_ID ,WORKFLOW_ID ,WORKFLOW_RUN_ID ,WORKLET_RUN_ID ,
INSTANCE_ID ,TASK_ID ,START_TIME

**Merge statement in Teradata:-**

```
MERGE INTO schema.INFA_TASK_RUN USING schema.INFA_TASK_RUN_STG src
ON
        INFA_TASK_RUN_RAW.SUBJECT_ID = src.SUBJECT_ID
AND     INFA_TASK_RUN_RAW.WORKFLOW_ID = src.WORKFLOW_ID
AND     INFA_TASK_RUN_RAW.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID = src.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID
AND     INFA_TASK_RUN_RAW.WORKLET_RUN_ID = src.WORKLET_RUN_ID
AND     INFA_TASK_RUN_RAW.INSTANCE_ID = src.INSTANCE_ID
AND     INFA_TASK_RUN_RAW.TASK_ID = src.TASK_ID
AND     INFA_TASK_RUN_RAW.START_TIME = src.START_TIME
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
        END_TIME = src.END_TIME
,       RUN_ERR_CODE = src.RUN_ERR_CODE
,       RUN_ERR_MSG = src.RUN_ERR_MSG
,       RUN_STATUS_CODE = src.RUN_STATUS_CODE
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(
                SUBJECT_AREA
        ,       WORKFLOW_NAME
        ,       VERSION_NUMBER
        ,       SUBJECT_ID
        ,       WORKFLOW_ID
        ,       WORKFLOW_RUN_ID
        ,       WORKLET_RUN_ID
        ,       CHILD_RUN_ID
        ,       INSTANCE_ID
        ,       INSTANCE_NAME
        ,       TASK_ID
        ,       TASK_TYPE_NAME
        ,       TASK_TYPE
        ,       START_TIME
        ,       END_TIME
        ,       RUN_ERR_CODE
        ,       RUN_ERR_MSG
        ,       RUN_STATUS_CODE
        ,       TASK_NAME
        ,       TASK_VERSION_NUMBER
        ,       SERVER_ID
        ,       SERVER_NAME
        )VALUES(
                src.SUBJECT_AREA
        ,       src.WORKFLOW_NAME
        ,       src.VERSION_NUMBER
        ,       src.SUBJECT_ID
        ,       src.WORKFLOW_ID
        ,       src.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID
        ,       src.WORKLET_RUN_ID
        ,       src.CHILD_RUN_ID
        ,       src.INSTANCE_ID
        ,       src.INSTANCE_NAME
        ,       src.TASK_ID
        ,       src.TASK_TYPE_NAME
        ,       src.TASK_TYPE
        ,       src.START_TIME
        ,       src.END_TIME
        ,       src.RUN_ERR_CODE
        ,       src.RUN_ERR_MSG
        ,       src.RUN_STATUS_CODE
        ,       src.TASK_NAME
        ,       src.TASK_VERSION_NUMBER
        ,       src.SERVER_ID
        ,       src.SERVER_NAME
        );
```

As I Know MYSQL DB doesn't support Merge statement. I am trying update and insert statement. but it doesn't seems to be right.

```
UPDATE schema.INFA_TASK_RUN tgt INNER JOIN schema.INFA_TASK_RUN_STG src
ON
       tgt.SUBJECT_ID = src.SUBJECT_ID
AND     tgt.WORKFLOW_ID = src.WORKFLOW_ID
AND     tgt.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID = src.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID
AND     tgt.WORKLET_RUN_ID = src.WORKLET_RUN_ID
AND     tgt.INSTANCE_ID = src.INSTANCE_ID
AND     tgt.TASK_ID = src.TASK_ID
AND     tgt.START_TIME = src.START_TIME
 SET
        tgt.END_TIME = src.END_TIME
,       tgt.RUN_ERR_CODE = src.RUN_ERR_CODE
,       tgt.RUN_ERR_MSG = src.RUN_ERR_MSG
,       tgt.RUN_STATUS_CODE = src.RUN_STATUS_CODE;

insert into schema.INFA_TASK_RUN (SUBJECT_AREA         ,       WORKFLOW_NAME         ,       VERSION_NUMBER         ,       SUBJECT_ID         ,       WORKFLOW_ID         ,       WORKFLOW_RUN_ID         ,       WORKLET_RUN_ID         ,       CHILD_RUN_ID         ,       INSTANCE_ID         ,       INSTANCE_NAME         ,       TASK_ID         ,       TASK_TYPE_NAME         ,       TASK_TYPE         ,       START_TIME         ,       END_TIME         ,       RUN_ERR_CODE         ,       RUN_ERR_MSG         ,       RUN_STATUS_CODE         ,       TASK_NAME         ,       TASK_VERSION_NUMBER         ,       SERVER_ID         ,       SERVER_NAME)
    select src.SUBJECT_AREA         ,       src.WORKFLOW_NAME         ,       src.VERSION_NUMBER         ,       src.SUBJECT_ID         ,       src.WORKFLOW_ID         ,       src.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID         ,       src.WORKLET_RUN_ID         ,       src.CHILD_RUN_ID         ,       src.INSTANCE_ID         ,       src.INSTANCE_NAME         ,       src.TASK_ID         ,       src.TASK_TYPE_NAME         ,       src.TASK_TYPE         ,       src.START_TIME         ,       src.END_TIME         ,       src.RUN_ERR_CODE         ,       src.RUN_ERR_MSG         ,       src.RUN_STATUS_CODE         ,       src.TASK_NAME         ,       src.TASK_VERSION_NUMBER         ,       src.SERVER_ID         ,       src.SERVER_NAME
    from schema.INFA_TASK_RUN_STG as src
        left outer join schema.INFA_TASK_RUN as tgt  ON
       tgt.SUBJECT_ID != src.SUBJECT_ID
AND     tgt.WORKFLOW_ID != src.WORKFLOW_ID
AND     tgt.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID != src.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID
AND     tgt.WORKLET_RUN_ID != src.WORKLET_RUN_ID
AND     tgt.INSTANCE_ID != src.INSTANCE_ID
AND     tgt.TASK_ID != src.TASK_ID
AND     tgt.START_TIME != src.START_TIME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe what you are looking for is something like this (Not tested and will only work when the primary key is set up correctly):

```
INSERT INTO schema.INFA_TASK_RUN (
     SUBJECT_AREA
    ,WORKFLOW_NAME
    ,VERSION_NUMBER
    ,SUBJECT_ID
    ,WORKFLOW_ID
    ,WORKFLOW_RUN_ID
    ,WORKLET_RUN_ID
    ,CHILD_RUN_ID
    ,INSTANCE_ID
    ,INSTANCE_NAME
    ,TASK_ID
    ,TASK_TYPE_NAME
    ,TASK_TYPE
    ,START_TIME
    ,END_TIME
    ,RUN_ERR_CODE
    ,RUN_ERR_MSG
    ,RUN_STATUS_CODE
    ,TASK_NAME
    ,TASK_VERSION_NUMBER
    ,SERVER_ID
    ,SERVER_NAME
    )
SELECT
     SUBJECT_AREA
    ,WORKFLOW_NAME
    ,VERSION_NUMBER
    ,SUBJECT_ID
    ,WORKFLOW_ID
    ,WORKFLOW_RUN_ID
    ,WORKLET_RUN_ID
    ,CHILD_RUN_ID
    ,INSTANCE_ID
    ,INSTANCE_NAME
    ,TASK_ID
    ,TASK_TYPE_NAME
    ,TASK_TYPE
    ,START_TIME
    ,END_TIME
    ,RUN_ERR_CODE
    ,RUN_ERR_MSG
    ,RUN_STATUS_CODE
    ,TASK_NAME
    ,TASK_VERSION_NUMBER
    ,SERVER_ID
    ,SERVER_NAME
FROM schema.INFA_TASK_RUN_STG src
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
     END_TIME = src.END_TIME
    ,RUN_ERR_CODE = src.RUN_ERR_CODE
    ,RUN_ERR_MSG = src.RUN_ERR_MSG
    ,RUN_STATUS_CODE = src.RUN_STATUS_CODE;
```

**Edit on 2020-05-21** to show separate update and insert statements based on the comments:

The INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY statement will probably be faster.

From the comments I tested the original statements to do the insert and update from the question.

Note your update statement works correctly.
Only issue is that every row is updated even if there were no changes.

Could be possible to add conditions to the join like 
    tgt.END_TIME != src.END_TIME
to ensure only changed records are updated.

**Original update query in your question:**

```
UPDATE schema.INFA_TASK_RUN tgt INNER JOIN schema.INFA_TASK_RUN_STG src
ON
       tgt.SUBJECT_ID = src.SUBJECT_ID
AND     tgt.WORKFLOW_ID = src.WORKFLOW_ID
AND     tgt.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID = src.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID
AND     tgt.WORKLET_RUN_ID = src.WORKLET_RUN_ID
AND     tgt.INSTANCE_ID = src.INSTANCE_ID
AND     tgt.TASK_ID = src.TASK_ID
AND     tgt.START_TIME = src.START_TIME
 SET
        tgt.END_TIME = src.END_TIME
,       tgt.RUN_ERR_CODE = src.RUN_ERR_CODE
,       tgt.RUN_ERR_MSG = src.RUN_ERR_MSG
,       tgt.RUN_STATUS_CODE = src.RUN_STATUS_CODE;
```

**Updated insert:**

Had to change the insert statement, please see the JOIN is where the columns are **equal** and we only select where there are no matching value in the target table with the check that the target table column is NULL:

```
INSERT INTO schema.INFA_TASK_RUN (
     SUBJECT_AREA
    ,WORKFLOW_NAME
    ,VERSION_NUMBER
    ,SUBJECT_ID
    ,WORKFLOW_ID
    ,WORKFLOW_RUN_ID
    ,WORKLET_RUN_ID
    ,CHILD_RUN_ID
    ,INSTANCE_ID
    ,INSTANCE_NAME
    ,TASK_ID
    ,TASK_TYPE_NAME
    ,TASK_TYPE
    ,START_TIME
    ,END_TIME
    ,RUN_ERR_CODE
    ,RUN_ERR_MSG
    ,RUN_STATUS_CODE
    ,TASK_NAME
    ,TASK_VERSION_NUMBER
    ,SERVER_ID
    ,SERVER_NAME
    )
    select src.SUBJECT_AREA
    ,src.WORKFLOW_NAME
    ,src.VERSION_NUMBER
    ,src.SUBJECT_ID
    ,src.WORKFLOW_ID
    ,src.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID
    ,src.WORKLET_RUN_ID
    ,src.CHILD_RUN_ID
    ,src.INSTANCE_ID
    ,src.INSTANCE_NAME
    ,src.TASK_ID
    ,src.TASK_TYPE_NAME
    ,src.TASK_TYPE
    ,src.START_TIME
    ,src.END_TIME
    ,src.RUN_ERR_CODE
    ,src.RUN_ERR_MSG
    ,src.RUN_STATUS_CODE
    ,src.TASK_NAME
    ,src.TASK_VERSION_NUMBER
    ,src.SERVER_ID
    ,src.SERVER_NAME
    FROM schema.INFA_TASK_RUN as tgt
        RIGHT JOIN schema.INFA_TASK_RUN_STG as src  ON
       tgt.SUBJECT_ID = src.SUBJECT_ID
AND     tgt.WORKFLOW_ID = src.WORKFLOW_ID
AND     tgt.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID = src.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID
AND     tgt.WORKLET_RUN_ID = src.WORKLET_RUN_ID
AND     tgt.INSTANCE_ID = src.INSTANCE_ID
AND     tgt.TASK_ID = src.TASK_ID
AND     tgt.START_TIME = src.START_TIME
WHERE tgt.SUBJECT_ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: Can you please explain why did you include end_time, run err code, run err, msg, run status code on duplicate key update. Is it correct combination ?

Comment: The `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is the same as the `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET` thus just used the same columns as your initial example. So when the **primary key** in table INFA_TASK_RUN match only those 4 columns will be updated, else a new record is inserted. Hope that explains it.

Comment: But I don't have any primary key in both table. So first time when I am trying to load it is inserting duplicate records 2 times. 443 records need to be insert but 886 records are getting loaded.

Comment: We are merging on these condition 
 INFA_TASK_RUN_RAW.SUBJECT_ID = src.SUBJECT_ID
AND     INFA_TASK_RUN_RAW.WORKFLOW_ID = src.WORKFLOW_ID
AND     INFA_TASK_RUN_RAW.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID = src.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID
AND     INFA_TASK_RUN_RAW.WORKLET_RUN_ID = src.WORKLET_RUN_ID
AND     INFA_TASK_RUN_RAW.INSTANCE_ID = src.INSTANCE_ID
AND     INFA_TASK_RUN_RAW.TASK_ID = src.TASK_ID
AND     INFA_TASK_RUN_RAW.START_TIME = src.START_TIME

Comment: In your original post you stated **Primary Index of schema.INFA_TASK_RUN :- SUBJECT_ID ,WORKFLOW_ID ,WORKFLOW_RUN_ID ,WORKLET_RUN_ID , INSTANCE_ID ,TASK_ID ,START_TIME**  MySql INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE only works with primary keys and is the fastest option you are going to get. The other option is to run separate sql statements 1 to insert if not found in the target table and then update is found.

Comment: Edited the answer to show the 2 separate statements. Believe you require that.

Comment: Piet, I liked your first answer which is more efficient. Can you have a look in other ques that seems to be tricky for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61932378/conversion-of-merge-statement-to-mysql-using-on-duplicate-key

Answer (score 0):

Correct Answer to avoid any confusion

```
 INSERT INTO schema.INFA_TASK_RUN (
         SUBJECT_AREA
        ,WORKFLOW_NAME
        ,VERSION_NUMBER
        ,SUBJECT_ID
        ,WORKFLOW_ID
        ,WORKFLOW_RUN_ID
        ,WORKLET_RUN_ID
        ,CHILD_RUN_ID
        ,INSTANCE_ID
        ,INSTANCE_NAME
        ,TASK_ID
        ,TASK_TYPE_NAME
        ,TASK_TYPE
        ,START_TIME
        ,END_TIME
        ,RUN_ERR_CODE
        ,RUN_ERR_MSG
        ,RUN_STATUS_CODE
        ,TASK_NAME
        ,TASK_VERSION_NUMBER
        ,SERVER_ID
        ,SERVER_NAME
        )
    SELECT
         SUBJECT_AREA
        ,WORKFLOW_NAME
        ,VERSION_NUMBER
        ,SUBJECT_ID
        ,WORKFLOW_ID
        ,WORKFLOW_RUN_ID
        ,WORKLET_RUN_ID
        ,CHILD_RUN_ID
        ,INSTANCE_ID
        ,INSTANCE_NAME
        ,TASK_ID
        ,TASK_TYPE_NAME
        ,TASK_TYPE
        ,START_TIME
        ,END_TIME
        ,RUN_ERR_CODE
        ,RUN_ERR_MSG
        ,RUN_STATUS_CODE
        ,TASK_NAME
        ,TASK_VERSION_NUMBER
        ,SERVER_ID
        ,SERVER_NAME
    FROM schema.INFA_TASK_RUN_STG src
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
         END_TIME = src.END_TIME
        ,RUN_ERR_CODE = src.RUN_ERR_CODE
        ,RUN_ERR_MSG = src.RUN_ERR_MSG
        ,RUN_STATUS_CODE = src.RUN_STATUS_CODE;
```