# Conversion of merge statement to MYSQL using on duplicate key

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Please suggest how to convert this teradata statement in MYSQL. As we know mysql doesn't support merge statement. Below 2 tables are also being used in select query and we have multiple primary key in each table.

```
MERGE INTO XYZ USING (
            SELECT
                    ITRR.WORKFLOW_NAME WORKFLOW_NAME
            ,       ITRR.INSTANCE_NAME INSTANCE_NAME
            ,       MIN(ITRR.START_TIME) EARLIEST_START_TIME
            ,       ITRR.SUBJECT_AREA SUBJECT_AREA
            ,       'INFORMATICA' PLATFORM_NAME
            FROM
                    ABC IWRR
            ,       DEF ITRR
            WHERE
                    IWRR.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID = ITRR.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID
            AND     IWRR.USER_NAME IN ('xyz')
            AND     ITRR.RUN_STATUS_CODE <> 2
            GROUP BY
                    ITRR.WORKFLOW_NAME
            ,       ITRR.INSTANCE_NAME
            ,       ITRR.SUBJECT_AREA
    ) SRC
    ON
            XYZ.PARENT_JOB_NAME = SRC.WORKFLOW_NAME
    AND     XYZ.CHILD_JOB_NAME  = SRC.INSTANCE_NAME
    AND     XYZ.SANDBOX         = SRC.SUBJECT_AREA
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET FIRST_EXECUTION = SRC.EARLIEST_START_TIME
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
    (
            PARENT_JOB_NAME
    ,       CHILD_JOB_NAME
    ,       FIRST_EXECUTION
    ,       SANDBOX
    ,       PLATFORM_NAME
    )VALUES
    (
            SRC.WORKFLOW_NAME
    ,       SRC.INSTANCE_NAME
    ,       SRC.EARLIEST_START_TIME
    ,       SRC.SUBJECT_AREA
    ,       SRC.PLATFORM_NAME
    );
```

I am trying below query but it is not working.

```
INSERT INTO XYZ (
                PARENT_JOB_NAME
,       CHILD_JOB_NAME
,       FIRST_EXECUTION
,       SANDBOX
,       PLATFORM_NAME
    )

       (SELECT
                ITRR.WORKFLOW_NAME WORKFLOW_NAME
        ,       ITRR.INSTANCE_NAME INSTANCE_NAME
        ,       MIN(ITRR.START_TIME) EARLIEST_START_TIME
        ,       ITRR.SUBJECT_AREA SUBJECT_AREA
        ,       'INFORMATICA' PLATFORM_NAME
        FROM
                ABC IWRR
        ,       DEF ITRR
        WHERE
                IWRR.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID = ITRR.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID
        AND     IWRR.USER_NAME IN ('XYZ')
        AND     ITRR.RUN_STATUS_CODE <> 2
        GROUP BY
                ITRR.WORKFLOW_NAME
        ,       ITRR.INSTANCE_NAME
        ,       ITRR.SUBJECT_AREA
 ) SRC
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       FIRST_EXECUTION = SRC.EARLIEST_START_TIME
```

Primary key of XYZ = `PARENT_JOB_NAME`

Primary key of ABC= `SUBJECT_ID`

Primary key of DEF= `SUBJECT_ID`,`WORKFLOW_ID`,`WORKFLOW_RUN_ID`,`WORKLET_RUN_ID`,`INSTANCE_ID`,`TASK_ID`,`START_TIME`

Comment: In `MERGE` I see `ON
            XYZ.PARENT_JOB_NAME = SRC.WORKFLOW_NAME
    AND     XYZ.CHILD_JOB_NAME  = SRC.INSTANCE_NAME
    AND     XYZ.SANDBOX         = SRC.SUBJECT_AREA` matching condition. So unique index by this 3-column combination must be created in `XYZ`.

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the code is supposed to be doing.  Also define what "not working" means.

Comment: Thanks Akina for beautiful explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax in MySQL is:

```
INSERT INTO XYZ (PARENT_JOB_NAME, CHILD_JOB_NAME, FIRST_EXECUTION, SANDBOX, PLATFORM_NAME)
    SELECT ITRR.WORKFLOW_NAME, ITRR.INSTANCE_NAME,
           MIN(ITRR.START_TIME), ITRR.SUBJECT_AREA, 'INFORMATICA'
    FROM ABC IWRR JOIN
         DEF ITRR
         ON IWRR.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID = ITRR.WORKFLOW_RUN_ID 
    WHERE IWRR.USER_NAME IN ('XYZ') AND
          ITRR.RUN_STATUS_CODE <> 2
    GROUP BY ITRR.WORKFLOW_NAME, ITRR.INSTANCE_NAME, ITRR.SUBJECT_AREA
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE FIRST_EXECUTION = VALUES(FIRST_EXECUTION);
```

Note the use of proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  Use it.

The major changes are

- Fixing the archaic syntax.
- Removing the parentheses are not needed for the `select` in an `insert . . . select` (although they are probably allowed).
- Removing the table alias, which is definitely not allowed.
- Fixing the `on duplicate key` statement.

Comment: Can you please explain  VALUES(FIRST_EXECUTION); and MIN(ITRR.START_TIME) .. how this thing is working

Comment: @Ashu . . . The documentation covers this:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values.  Note that this is deprecated in the most recent versions, but it will be a long time before it actually goes away.

Comment: Please have a look on below post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62169244/conversion-of-teradata-sql-to-mysql-sql

Answer (score 0):

Believe the comment from @Akina is correct and that the primary key on the table XYZ is just incorrect.

The primary key on the XYZ table need to include these columns `PARENT_JOB_NAME, CHILD_JOB_NAME and SANDBOX` for the mysql `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` statement to work correctly.

Comment: MERGE statement allows any interfere condition. In MySQL, only interfere by unique index is implemented. This is true. 3-field composite index is just a guess. MERGE may work even when interfere condition expression is not unique...