# Conversion of Teradata sql to MYSQL sql

Tags: mysql, date, casting, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I want to convert Teradata query into MYSQL query.

Datatype of **START_TIME** AND **END_TIME** is `TIMESTAMP(6)`

**Teradata query:-**

```
select START_TIME,END_TIME, (EXTRACT(DAY    FROM (END_TIME - START_TIME DAY(4) TO SECOND)) * 86400) from base.xyz
```

Result is like:-

```
**START_TIME, END_TIME, CALCULATED_FIELD**

9/15/2017 16:22:52.000000   9/19/2017 15:14:02.000000   259,200
7/26/2014 07:00:04.000000   7/28/2014 12:55:55.000000   172,800
6/8/2018 16:59:19.000000    6/11/2018 09:56:23.000000   172,800
10/6/2017 17:52:06.000000   10/9/2017 15:47:35.000000   172,800
7/29/2014 02:40:00.000000   7/30/2014 04:09:56.000000   86,400
7/25/2014 08:33:35.000000   7/25/2014 09:43:34.000000   0
1/6/2015 13:56:52.000000    1/6/2015 13:57:29.000000    0
```

Please suggest what would be mysql query

Comment: It's better to define the result which you want to achieve from your source START_TIME and END_TIME values.

Comment: Thanks Akina for complement. I have updated the result

Comment: Please define the meaning of the result which you need... now it looks like the amount of whole days between dates converted to seconds.

Comment: seems to be correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT start_time,
       end_time,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, start_time, end_time) * 86400
FROM base.xyz;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e3240c24f1b1f3c6c00c4ab71813b80)